# Make ls distinguish scripts from binaries in output

Tags: scripting, ls, cat, binary

Is it possible to make `ls` distinguish executable scripts from actual compiled binaries?

The permissions are most often the same (`+x`), and with `ls -F` you get an asterisk suffix (`*`) for both, so it's hard to tell them apart. I have a script to setup the colors of `ls`, but it relies on the file being executable or not, so they show up the same:

```
BG='01;32'  # green
EX="ex=$BG" # file with execute permission
```

I don't want to depend on the extension as so many of these files don't have it.

I want this so when I see some bizarre error message and think, "What code caused that?", I know whether or not it's safe to `cat` the file.

If there is no standard solution, what about parsing the output of `file`, in one common function, and inserting some distinctive mark? Or would that be much too slow for `ls`?

Comment: At the bare minimum you'll probably have to check (as in read) the first 2 bytes of every executable file you `ls` (`#!` probably means script, `^?E` probably means the start of a binary).  How much of an effect this has probably depends on things like your file system and directory layout and whether you are using spinning disks or solid state, etc.  If you do that you probably want `noatime` or `relatime`.  I think it would be much easier to just run `file` manually on the few files you want to inspect, unless you truly want to do this for every `ls`.

Comment: @jw013: Hm, maybe it is smarter to base that check on `cat`, and not `ls`? I could call it `ct` or something similar so it won't interfere with other use of `cat`.

Comment: That's probably a better way to go - replace `cat` with a shell function that checks if it's a binary file first and warns before outputting to a terminal.  I think `less` already does this check.

Comment: Why do you need this for every file? Just check `file` before catting something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the contents of a file to distinguish between binaries and scripts. `ls` won't do this, it only looks at file names and metadata (type, permission, etc.).

Here's a crude parser for `file` that colors scripts and binaries differently. It acts like `ls -d`; adding metadata would require a patch-up job that calls for a more direct approach (e.g. in Perl or Python); use `lsx somedir/*` to list the contents of a directory. File names are assumed not to contain newlines nor colons (you can change the `:` separator for some other string with the `-F` option to `file`).

```
lsx () {
  file -iN -- "$@" |
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    name=${line%%: *}; type=${line#*: }
    color=0
    case $type in
      application/x-executable*) color='32';;
      text/x-shellscript*) color='01;32';;
      application/*zip*) color='31';;
    esac
    printf '\033[%sm%s\033[0m\n' "$color" "$name"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with `dircolors`. Have a look at the output of `dircolors -p`. On my systems I find the following relevant definitions:

```
# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;32
…
# Or if you want to colorize scripts even if they do not have the
# executable bit actually set.
#.sh 01;32
```

If you remove the `#` at the last line and write `.sh 07;31` your shell scripts (all files with extension `.sh`) will blink in red color.

Save your settings in `~/.dircolors` and add to your `.bashrc` the line:

```
eval "$(dircolor $HOME/.dircolors)"
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. It's very far from a silver bullet solution (as I said, a lot of scripts don't have extensions), and those who do... well, you already know they are scripts (unless you go crazy naming binaries)! Right now, I can't see how this would help me but ... what the heck, I've been wrong before. +1

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read about your naming schemes. However in that case you have to check the output of `file`. I would assume that zsh has a solution for your case, but I'm not sure about this.